# Insertar productos a woocommerce no muestra el precio

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Buenas comunidad, estoy teniendo un problema y no se como solucionarlo. Estoy introduciendo los datos vía PHP y tengo el problema que el precio no lo muestra en la captura tenéis aquí:
**Captura_1)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Captura_2)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio entras a la ficha del producto y si que se muestran los precios introducidos correctamente. Cuando simplemente actualizo el producto, automáticamente se rellena el campo Precio que antes no se mostraba. ¿Sabéis porque ocurre eso?

```
$post = array(
        'post_title'        =>  $qwe,
        'post_content'      =>  $content
}
update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_regular_price', $precioAnterior); 
update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_sale_price', $precio);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se ha solucionado este problema, simplemente añadiendo la siguiente linea de código, que sirve para darle el precio base.

```
update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_price', $precioAnterior);
```